# Using terraform how can I create one service account used across multiple project?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am currently trying to use a service account that is already created in one project and use it again in a different project. I do not want to create a new service account in the new project I want to use the already existing service account. I am clueless on how to go about implementing this.

Comment: An answer depends on what you want to do with the service account. Use the service account to grant permissions to multiple projects or include the service as a data resource in Terraform HCL? Edit your question and show how you are using the service account and the problem/error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html) terraform. But I think u need grant permisions or roles for the new project in this sa.